# In a bash script, how can I bind a key to a function?

Tags: bash, key-bindings

I did the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
a=2

function up_a() {
    a=$((a+1));
}

while (true);
do
    echo "a=$a";
    up_a;
    sleep 1;
done
```

It's working fine:

```
$ ./test.sh
a=2
a=3
...
```

Now, I try the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
a=2

function up_a() {
    a=$((a+1));
}

bind -x '"p": up_a';

while (true);
do
    echo "a=$a";
    sleep 1;
done
```

When I test it:

```
$ . test.sh
```

(I need to "import" the script to use `bind` command, with `source` or `.`)

```
a=2
a=2
...
```

(I pressed the "p" key several times)

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Key bindings using `bind` only affect the interactive text input (the *readline* library). When running a program (even a built-in `while`) the terminal is switched to standard "cooked" mode and input is given to the currently running program (in this case, `sleep` would receive the input).

You can read the keys manually:

```
read -N 1 input

echo "Read '$input'"
```

However, if you want to run the `while` loop *and* read input at the same time, you will have to do it in separate processes (bash does not support threads). Since variables are local to a process, the end result will have to be fairly complicated.